# incremented define?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is there anyways to have a define increment every time you use it?

For example

```
int a = ADEFINE;
int b = ADEFINE;
```

a is 1 and b is 2.

Comment: What for? There may be better ways depending on your situation.

Comment: I want to give every class a unique number.

Comment: You need a constantly changing and unqie compile-time constant, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need compile-time-constants, you could do something like this to enumerate classes:

```
int counter() {
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
}

template<class T>
int id() { 
    static int i = counter();
    return i; 
};

class A {};
class B {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << id<A>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << id<B>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `__COUNTER__`, though it's not standard. Both MSVC++ and GCC support it.

---

If you can use boost, the [pre-processor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) has an implementation of counter. Here's the example from the documentation:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>

BOOST_PP_COUNTER // 0

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

BOOST_PP_COUNTER // 1

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

BOOST_PP_COUNTER // 2

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

BOOST_PP_COUNTER // 3
```

(Kudo's to gf)

Comment: Although this doesn't affect the asker, one should note that `__COUNTER__` only works for GCC ≥4.3. (Xcode, for instance, only bundles with GCC 4.2.)

Comment: I just noticed that Boost.Preprocessor provides a portable version of `__COUNTER__` (kind of): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

```
static int PUT_AN_UNUSED_NAME_HERE = 0;
#define ADEFINE (++PUT_AN_UNUSED_NAME_HERE)
```

Comment: This isn't compile time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `__LINE__`?  It's standard C89/C99/C++.

Comment: Because `a` and `b` maybe both on line 14 in different files?