# Macro increase value and then concatenate

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation

I want to create a recursive Macro the will create the "next" class.

Example:

```
#define PRINTME(indexNum) class m_##(indexNum+1) { }
```

The `indexNum + 1` is evaluated as an `int`, and won't concatenate to the class name.

How can I cause the compiler to evaluate that, before concatenating?

Comment: I'm not really sure you *can*: The preprocessor only performs lexical manipulations; it does not know the rules of C++ or can evaluate expressions.

Comment: I'm not really sure you *should*: readability, maintainability etc.

Comment: Can't you just put your classes in an list or array?

Comment: I can to this with templates. I'm just wondering if it can be done with macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't.  The preprocessor generally deals in text and tokens; the only place arithmetic is carried out in in `#if` and `#elif` directives.

Also, macro expansion isn't recursive.  During expansion, the macro being expanded is disabled, and is not available for further substitution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate unique class names every time the `PRINTME` is invoked then, following is one way:

```
#define CONCATE1(X,Y) X##Y
#define CONCATE(X,Y)  CONCATE1(X,Y)

#define PRINTME class CONCATE(m_,__COUNTER__) {}
```

`__COUNTER__` is an extension in gcc and I am not sure if it's present in other compilers. It's guaranteed that compiler will add 1 every time this macro is invoked.
(In this case, you cannot use `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` effectively.)

[Demo](http://ideone.com/m3s2t).

Comment: Nice Macro, didn't know it existed.

Comment: Do you know if __COUNTER__ is compilertime thread safe? i mean if the compiler is processing 8 files at the same time, will __COUNTER__ be continuous for the same file ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer, `__COUNTER__` happens at preprocessing stage (even before compilation starts) so nothing to do with thread safety. And it's always unique across several files. You can give it a try in a test program.

Answer (score 3):

Well it is doable, based on your motivation and ability to endure ugly code. First off define increment macro:

```
#define PLUS_ONE(x) PLUS_ONE_##x

#define PLUS_ONE_0 1
#define PLUS_ONE_1 2
#define PLUS_ONE_2 3
#define PLUS_ONE_3 4
#define PLUS_ONE_4 5
#define PLUS_ONE_5 6
#define PLUS_ONE_7 8
#define PLUS_ONE_8 9
#define PLUS_ONE_9 10
// and so on...
```

You can't just use `PLUS_ONE(x)` in concatenation operation, since preprocessor won't expand it. There is a way, however - you can abuse the fact that the preprocessor expands variadic arguments.

```
// pass to variadic macro to expand an argument
#define PRINTME(indexNum)       PRINTME_PRIMITIVE(PLUS_ONE(indexNum))
// do concatenation
#define PRINTME_PRIMITIVE(...)  class m_ ## __VA_ARGS__ { }
```

Done!

```
PRINTME(1); // expands to class m_2 { };
```

Have you considered using templates instead?

Comment: Yes, i have a working example with templates. Was just wondering about macros

Comment: And how do you find my anwser?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr this didn't work for me: http://cpp.sh/63cwi
Is there anythin I have dome wrong? Can you paste a working example? Thanks

Comment: @YochaiTimmer can you please send me your working solution with templates? Thanks