# Macro-based counter

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-preprocessor

Is it possible to create compile time constants like this:

```
// event.h
#define REGISTER_EVENT_TYPE() ... // Returns last_returned_number+1

// header1
#define SOME_EVENT REGISTER_EVENT_TYPE()
// header2
#define SOME_OTHER_EVENT REGISTER_EVENT_TYPE()
```

Where `SOME_EVENT` will be 0 and `SOME_OTHER_EVENT` will be 1.

Tried the following code:

```
#define DEF_X(x) const int x = BOOST_PP_COUNTER;
#define REGISTER_EVENT_TYPE(x) BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()DEF_X(x)

#include REGISTER_EVENT_TYPE(SOME_EVENT_TYPE)
```

But include eats constant declaration.

Comment: You want a macro that returns a different constant every time it is "called"? I'm pretty sure that is not possible.

Comment: Macros is compile-time, and you are asking for data in execution time... It can't be posible.

Comment: Similar question and possible answer using enum:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74426878/917198

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but with `const/constexpr int` and with Boost.Preprocessor.

See [BOOST_PP_COUNTER](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html)

An example of usage:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>

constexpr int A  = BOOST_PP_COUNTER; // 0

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

constexpr int B = BOOST_PP_COUNTER; // 1

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

constexpr int C = BOOST_PP_COUNTER; // 2

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

constexpr int D = BOOST_PP_COUNTER; // 3
```

See [working example](http://ideone.com/U41IRe).

---

Final note: don't use macro for storing results, you'll get the same number in the end in all such defined constants:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>

#define A  BOOST_PP_COUNTER // A is 0

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

#define B BOOST_PP_COUNTER // B is 1, but A is 1 too

int main() { cout << A << B << endl; }
```

Output:

```
 11
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know about BOOST_PP_COUNTER, and I am trying to find a way to wrap following code to single macro.
`constexpr int A  = BOOST_PP_COUNTER;  #include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()`

Comment: @DejaVu - please remember to always add or at least mention what have you tried so far. Anyway: I leave this answer. I hope it serves for others.

Comment: @DejaVu - answering on your question in comment: Well - you cannot have `#` in macro definition. I am afraid you need two lines of code for new ID, or, why don't you just use `enum`...