# Count source file lines using macros?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is it possible, using the C/C++ preprocessor, to count lines within a source file, into either a macro or some kind compile-time-available value? E.g. can I replace `MAGIC1`, `MAGIC2` and `MAGIC3` in the following, and get the value 4 somehow when using `MAGIC3`?

```
MAGIC1 // can be placed wherever you like before the relevant 
       // lines - either right before them, or in global scope etc.
foo(); MAGIC2
bar(); MAGIC2
baz(); MAGIC2
quux(); MAGIC2
// ... possibly a bunch of code here; not guaranteed to be in same scope ...
MAGIC3
```

Notes:

- Compiler-specific extensions to the preprocessor's capabilities are acceptable but undesirable.
- If this is possible only with the help of some of C++, as opposed to C, construct, that's also acceptable but undesirable (i.e. I'd like something that would work for C).
- Obviously this can be done by running the source file through some external processor script, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: There's [a macro called `__LINE__`](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html) that represents the current line number

Comment: you want to count only lines annotated with `MAGIC2`, right?

Comment: Are searching for `__COUNTER__` and/or `BOOST_PP_COUNTER`?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724307/macro-based-counter) help?

Comment: Assuming a hypothetical preprocessor-based solution, what kind of preprocessed C code are you trying to get?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Yes, but that's just one possibly approach I had in my mind for achieving the line counting.

Comment: @PSkocik: I want something I could use as a compile-time constant, e.g. for saying `int arr[MAGIC4]` and get the number of lines in some previously-counted section of my code.

Comment: @user1810087: That is one approach (in which we actively write something to increase the counter with every line). But the question there seems focused on using Boost's preprocessor utilities.

Comment: I'm still really curious what kind of problem requires the code to have data structures based on its own code formatting/layout. Is this for some code golf challenge? :D

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Actually, unit tests. I want to have each line check something, and append the result to some array, the memory for which - for certain reasons - needs to be allocated statically. But I don't want to spell out how many checks I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A somewhat more robust solution, allowing for different counters (as long as they don't intermix, and there's no use of `__COUNTER__` for other tasks):

```
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE(s1, s2)

#define COUNT_THIS_LINE static_assert(__COUNTER__ + 1, "");
#define START_COUNTING_LINES(count_name) \
  enum { EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(count_name, _start) = __COUNTER__ };
#define FINISH_COUNTING_LINES(count_name) \
  enum { count_name = __COUNTER__ - EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(count_name, _start) - 1 };
```

This hides the implementation details (although it hides them inside macros...). It is a generalization of @MaxLanghof's answer. Note that `__COUNTER__` may have a non-zero value when we start a count.

Here's how it's used:

```
START_COUNTING_LINES(ze_count)

int hello(int x) {
    x++;
    /* some */     COUNT_THIS_LINE
    void source(); COUNT_THIS_LINE
    void lines();  COUNT_THIS_LINE
    return x;
}

FINISH_COUNTING_LINES(ze_count)

int main()
{
    return ze_count;
}
```

Also, this is valid C - if your preprocessor supports `__COUNTER__`, that is.

[Works on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ELmMbq).

If you're using C++, you can modify this solution to not even pollute the global namespace - by placing the counters within `namespace macro_based_line_counts { ... }`, or `namespace detail` etc.)

Answer (score 15):

There is the `__LINE__` preprocessor macro which gives you an integer for the line is appeared on. You could take its value on some line, and then some later line, and compare.

```
static const int BEFORE = __LINE__;
foo();
bar();
baz();
quux();
static const int AFTER = __LINE__;
static const int COUNT = AFTER - BEFORE - 1; // 4
```

If you want to count the occurrences of something rather than source lines, `__COUNTER__` might be a non-standard option, supported by *some* compilers such as GCC and MSVC.

```
#define MAGIC2_2(c)
#define MAGIC2(c) MAGIC2_2(c)
static const int BEFORE = __COUNTER__;
void foo(); MAGIC2(__COUNTER__);
void bar(
    int multiple,
    float lines); MAGIC2(__COUNTER__);
void baz(); MAGIC2(__COUNTER__);
void quux(); MAGIC2(__COUNTER__);
static const int AFTER = __COUNTER__;
static const int COUNT = AFTER - BEFORE - 1; // 4
```

I took the initial value of `__COUNTER__` because it might have been used previously in the source file, or some included header.

In C rather than C++ there are limitations on constant variables, so an `enum` might be used instead.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    FOO = COUNT // C: error: enumerator value for ‘FOO’ is not an integer constant
};
```

Replacing the const with `enum`:

```
enum {BEFORE = __LINE__};
foo();
bar();
baz();
quux();
enum { COUNT = __LINE__ - BEFORE - 1};
enum MyEnum
{
    FOO = COUNT // OK
};
```

Comment: I think this is about the closest as you can get with just the preprocessor. The preprocessor is one-pass, so you can't backpatch a later computed value, but global-variable references will work and should optimize the same. They just won't work at integer constants expressions, but it might be possible to structure the code so that those aren't needed for the counts.

Comment: `__COUNTER__` is not standard in C or C++.   If you know it works with particular compilers, specify them.

Comment: @einpoklum no, `BEFORE` and `AFTER` aren't macros

Comment: There's a problem with the non-counter version of this solution: the before and after are usable only in the same scope as the source lines. Edited my "e.g." snippet to reflect that this is an issue.

Comment: Note that this solution will not work on standard C compiler, because constant variables cannot be used in constant expressions. To get around that, you should declare `BEFORE` and `AFTER` as enum constants.

Comment: @user694733 True question was tagged [C++]. For C enum constants work.

Answer (score 9):

I know that the OP's request is to use macros, but I would like to add another way of doing this that does not involve using macros.

C++20 introduces the `source_location` class that represents certain information about the source code, such as file names, line numbers, and function names. We can use that pretty easily in this case.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

static constexpr auto line_number_start = std::source_location::current().line();
void foo();
void bar();
static constexpr auto line_number_end = std::source_location::current().line();

int main() {
    std::cout << line_number_end - line_number_start - 1 << std::endl; // 2

    return 0;
}
```

And live example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:7),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cexperimental/source_location%3E%0A%0Astatic+constexpr+auto+line_number_start+%3D+std::experimental::source_location::current().line()%3B%0Avoid+foo()%3B%0Avoid+bar()%3B%0Astatic+constexpr+auto+line_number_end+%3D+std::experimental::source_location::current().line()%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+line_number_end+-+line_number_start+-+1+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:56.69638920801932,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:cmcstl2,ver:trunk)),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:43.303610791980674,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:43.303610791980674,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Comment: Without macros is even better than with macros. However - with this approach, I can only use the line count in the same scope as the lines I've counted. Also - with `source_location` be experimental in C++20?

Comment: I agree that solution without macros is far better than with macros. `source_location` is now officially part of C++20. Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location). I just couldn't find the version of gcc compiler on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) that already supports it in non experimental sense. Can you please explain a bit more your statement -  *I can only use the line count in the same scope as the lines I've counted*?

Comment: Suppose I put your suggestion within a function (i.e. the lines counted are invocations, not declarations). It works - but I only have `line_number_start` and `line_number_end` within that scope, nowhere else. If I want it elsewhere I need to pass it at run-time - which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Take a look at the example that standard provides [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location). If it is default argument, then it is still part of compile-time, right?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make `line_number_end` visible at compile-time outside its scope. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer with an example because I think I didn't get what you think. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NutCraker: Done.

Comment: @einpoklum will take a look at it a bit later this evening

Comment: @einpoklum I tried few things but could not get it to work at compile-time. So I suppose it's either not possible or I don't have enough knowledge to get it working. Btw I tried running your example from your answer but `num_counted_lines` is still 0 at the end.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness: If you're willing to add `MAGIC2` after every line, you can use `__COUNTER__`:

```
#define MAGIC2 static_assert(__COUNTER__ + 1, "");

/* some */     MAGIC2
void source(); MAGIC2
void lines();  MAGIC2

constexpr int numberOfLines = __COUNTER__;

int main()
{
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/i8fDLx (returns `3`)

You can make it reusable by storing the start and end values of `__COUNTER__`.

Overall this is really cumbersome though. You also won't be able to count lines that contain preprocessor directives or that end with `//` comments. I'd use `__LINE__` instead, see the other answer.

Comment: why do you use `static_assert` ?

Comment: This gave "9" in the source file i dropped it into, you can't assume `__COUNTER__` is still zero initially as other headers, etc. might use it.

Comment: you have to use the value of `__COUNTER__` twice and take the difference

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 `__COUNTER__` on it's own wouldn't be allowed, and it needs to get expanded to something or it won't count (I can't remember the rules 100% on this).

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comment, if you want to specify a (compile-time) array size in C or C++, you can do

```
int array[]; //incomplete type
enum{ LINE0 = __LINE__ }; //enum constants are integer constant expressions
/*lines to be counted; may use array (though not sizeof(array)) */
/*...*/
int array[ __LINE__ - LINE0 ]; //complete the definition of int array[]
```

If you need `sizeof(array)` in the intervening lines, you can replace it with a static variable reference (unless it absolutely needs to be an integer constant expression) and an optimizing compiler should treat it just the same (eliminate the need for the static variable to be placed in memory)

```
int array[]; static int count;
enum{ LINE0 = __LINE__ }; //enum constants are integer constant expressions
//... possibly use count here
enum { LINEDIFF = __LINE__ - LINE0 }; 
int array[ LINEDIFF ]; /*complete the definition of int array[]*/ 
static int count = LINEDIFF; //fill the count in later
```

A `__COUNTER__`-based solution (if that extension is available) as opposed to a `__LINE__`-based one will work the same.

`constexpr`s in C++ should work as well as `enum`, but `enum` will work in plain C as well (my solution above is a plain C solution).

Comment: This will work only if my use of the line-count is in the same scope as the counted lines. IIANM. Note I edited my question slightly to emphasize that could be an issue.

Comment: @einpoklum A `__COUNTER__` based solution has issues too: you better hope your magic macro is the only user of `__COUNTER__`, at least before you're done with your use of `__COUNTER__`. The problem basically all comes down to the simple facts that `__COUNTER__/__LINE__` are preprocessor features and the preprocessor works in one pass, so you can't backpatch an integer constant expression later based on `__COUNTER__`/`__LINE__`. The only way (in C at least) is to avoid the need in the first place, e.g., by using forward array declarations without size (incompletely typed array declarations).

Comment: For the record, the `\ ` does not affect `__LINE__` - if there is a line break, `__LINE__` increases. [Example 1](https://godbolt.org/z/UXXPsG), [example 2](https://godbolt.org/z/6dnHuZ).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks. Didn't realize that. Fixed.