# What does #define macro() <...> do?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, c-preprocessor

What does this line do?
I doubt its a template or expression. (doing those divies and naming a member hpp is a bad idea)

```
# define BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER() <boost/preprocessor/slot/detail/counter.hpp>
```

Full file

```
# /* **************************************************************************
#  *                                                                          *
#  *     (C) Copyright Paul Mensonides 2005.                                  *
#  *     Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See      *
#  *     accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at                         *
#  *     http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)                                *
#  *                                                                          *
#  ************************************************************************** */
#
# /* See http://www.boost.org for most recent version. */
#
# ifndef BOOST_PREPROCESSOR_SLOT_COUNTER_HPP
# define BOOST_PREPROCESSOR_SLOT_COUNTER_HPP
#
# include <boost/preprocessor/slot/detail/def.hpp>
#
# /* BOOST_PP_COUNTER */
#
# define BOOST_PP_COUNTER 0
#
# /* BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER */
#
# define BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER() <boost/preprocessor/slot/detail/counter.hpp>
#
# endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apparently it does some auto-incrementing magic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076757/incremented-define/2076775#2076775)

Here's [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/update_counter.html).

I have no idea how it works. What I do know is that the magic is in counter.hpp itself; that the definition you posted has brackets in it is just so that you can write the vaguely user-friendly:

```
#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()
```

to invoke said magic.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a "shortcut" so you can do

```
#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()
```

in your code rather than know the details of how that feature is implemented.

See this question [Incremented define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076757/incremented-define)'s answers for some usage example.